# What do the symbols in the OP refer to?

Tags: theme-song, the-world-god-only-knows

In the opening theme song of The World God Only Knows, a couple of symbols fly around the screen.

This one seems to matches the loose soul detector that Elsie wears on her head
[image: 1]
[image]

However, i don't understand the references in the other icons:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

What do these symbols mean?

Comment: At least two of them related directly to New Hell and the Runaway Spirits Squad.  It's a hunch but I think they're all related to them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The icon with a jar is the Weiss capturing device.

---

*I don't know what the bear like icon refers to*

---

The cat icon references the design of Kanon's stun gun as it appears in the anime. (The stun gun has normal appearance in the manga). The icon matches the stun gun on Kanon's right hand in the image below.

[image: Kanon's stun gun in anime]

According to [KamiNomi Wiki](http://kaminomi.wikia.com/wiki/Kanon%27s_Stun_Guns):

> The original shape of the stun guns were replaced by kitten-style appearance in the anime as a safety image.

---

The hexagon icon is the Maijima emblem, which is shown most clearly in chapter 169. For the purpose of comparison:

[image: Maijima emblem]

---

The last 4 icons are Hellian alphabet. Referring to below chart from [this forum posting by EyZi](http://forum.redhawkscans.com/showthread.php?1532-Apollo-s-Message-Decoded&p=71029&viewfull=1#post71029):

[image: Hellian]

The characters are G, O, N, K, in order from left to right, top to bottom.